# How to generate SSH1 key using ssh-keygen for SSH2

Tags: ssh-keygen

I have 2 machines running on Linux. One has ssh2 configured **SOURCE** and another has ssh1 configured **DESTINATION**. How do I generate a key pair in **SOURCE** whose public key can be understood by **DESTINATION**? Ideally I need to generate a SSH1 key pair using my installed ssh-keygen in a SOURCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate v1/v2 SSH keys with `ssh-keygen -t rsa1` or `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.  Then you can copy your key from SOURCE to DESTINATION (and vice-versa) with `ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: Oops editing my answer: ssh-keygen generates v2 keys by default, so you'd only need to say `ssh-keygen -t rsa1` if you want a v1 key, and say `ssh-keygen -t rsa` if you want a v2 key.

Comment: You may want to "edit" your previous reply directly :)

Comment: Already did, but thanks.  Still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Command to generate the key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

To Copy use the command give your source and destination

```
ssh-copy-id
```

You can change the permission to 700 in .ssh folder

```
chmod 700 ............
```

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. This one generates ssh2 key. Actual answer has been given by @RSD3